# Not re-rendering in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why my Array is not re-rendering?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [arr,setArr] = useState([5,4,3,2,1]);
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        let newArr = arr;
        newArr[0]++;
        setArr(newArr);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {arr.map((item) => (
                <h1 key={item}>{item}</h1>
            ))}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>buttong</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are using the same array instance to set the new state. React checks the identity and if that didn't change it does not re-render. Make a copy like this `const newArray = [...oldArray];`

Answer (score 5):

Never mutate the state in React.

`let newArr = arr;` by doing so, you're assigning a reference of the `arr` in `newArr` not it's values. So when you do `newArr[0]++;` you're mutating the state because `newArr` is a reference to `arr` array.

Here `const newArr = [...arr];` we are taking a copy of the `arr` values using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and then mutating the copy not the state and then updating the state with `setArr(newArr);`

Learn about Difference Between Pass by Values and References: https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/

Try this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);
  const handleClick = () => {
    const newArr = [...arr];
    newArr[0]++;
    setArr(newArr);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {arr.map((item) => {
        return <h1 key={item}>{item}</h1>;
      })}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>buttong</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```